# Webservices with long task threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to develop two applications, one in windows forms and other need to be a background application(local server) develop in c# too. So this applications need communicate with each other to send data required by the first app and update data in the local server.

I would like to communicate by webservices, the problem is that when you call a service application that can trigger tasks in the backgroun app(local server) that can take a long time, regardless of the response webservice is possible to do this in c #?

I research things like WCF, and i think is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by Scott Hanselman, it mentions libraries like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or the [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/) API for such tasks.